# How to force Castle.DynamicProxy to ignore changing versions of dependencies

Tags: c#, aop, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I use `Castle.DynamicProxy` for AOP. My IoC container is `Ninject 3.2` and after it returns resolved dependencies, I put the most of them to a Castle-based wrapper. (I can't use `Ninject.Extensions.Interception` as it conflicts with `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions for NInject 3.0.1.0/3.2`)

The problem is that my code depends on binaries (signed assemblies) that change everyday (my code is a test framework for a bunch of products). If an assembly ships with a new version, Castle begins throwing an exception "`There was an error in static constructor on type Castle.Proxies.[MyClassName]Proxy. This is likely a bug in DynamicProxy. Please report it.".`

My code with Castle:

```
internal static T ResolveAndProxify<T>(object[] arguments, params IParameter[] parameters) where T : class
{
    var objectToProxy = default(T);
    if (null == parameters || 0 == parameters.Length) {
        objectToProxy = _kernel.Get<T>(new IParameter[] {});
    } else {
        objectToProxy = _kernel.Get<T>(parameters);
    }
    if (/* condition not to proxify */) {
        return objectToProxy;
    } else {
        if (null == arguments || 0 == arguments.Length) {
            return (T)_proxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(
                typeof(T),
                new LoggingAspect(), new ErrorHandlingAspect());
        } else {
            return (T)_proxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(
                typeof(T),
                arguments,
                new LoggingAspect(), new ErrorHandlingAspect());
        }
    }
}
```

If I turn off Castle, all works:

```
internal static T ResolveAndProxify<T>(object[] arguments, params IParameter[] parameters) where T : class
{
    var objectToProxy = default(T);
    if (null == parameters || 0 == parameters.Length) {
        objectToProxy = _kernel.Get<T>(new IParameter[] {});
    } else {
        objectToProxy = _kernel.Get<T>(parameters);
    }

    return objectToProxy;
}
```

Declaration and creation of Castle compoments:

```
private static readonly ProxyGenerator _proxyGenerator;

// I tried several ways
var scope = new ModuleScope(false, true);
var proxyBuilder = new DefaultProxyBuilder(scope);
var proxyArgument = new ConstructorArgument("builder", proxyBuilder);
_proxyGenerator = _kernel.Get<ProxyGenerator>(proxyArgument);

Bind<ProxyGenerator>().ToConstructor(arg => new ProxyGenerator(arg.Inject<IProxyBuilder()));
```

I saw here at `stackoverflow.com`a sample (in the comments) how to switch off caching or something that ties Castle to an exact version of the assembly, for Castle Windsor. How to do the same without `Castle Windsor`?

Comment: I also tried as said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553004/castle-dynamicproxy-interceptor-having-problems-with-different-assemblies) to set up the proxy generator - the same problem.
`_proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue partially.
I noticed that the exception throws only on specific classes.
For example:

```
public virtual ObjectTypeFromThirdPartySignedAssembly PropertyName { get; set; }

public virtual ObjectTypeFromThirdPartySignedAssembly MethodName()
{
}

public virtual void Method2(ObjectTypeFromThirdPartySignedAssembly inputObject)
{
}
```

As can be seen, the proxy works here directly with dependencies. Since I found the root of problem, I skipped these classes from proxifying. This is not the best solution, of course, nonetheless I could use logging, error handling and other interceptors to wrap a part of my classes.